# Hide UIButton title when using autolayout

Tags: ios, uibutton, autolayout

Hey I'm learning developing in XCode with Storyboard and I have an UIButton with custom image. Before I developed without Autolayout but then I read about it and decided to try it. My problem is that the button has a custom image and it shouldn't display a title, only the image. When I don't use Autolayout everything works just fine (only image is displayed). But when I turn Autolayout on, it resizes my picture and pushes it to left and shows button title next to the image. How can I display only the image using Autolayout? Has this something to do with intrinsic content size??

Comment: OK, got it to work with `[button setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];` but is this the only way?

Answer (score 0):

Try my answer:

```
button.titleLabel.hidden=YES;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to:

```
button.autoresizesSubviews=NO;
```

Or:

```
button.titleLabel=UIViewAutoresizingNone;
```

Or:

```
button.imageView.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingNone;
```

Comment: First one doesn't work, second one gives compiler error "Assignment to readonly property" and third one doesn't do anything either. I've got to tell the UIButton somehow that "Hey, don't resize my button image". I tried the first option myself, but nothing.

Comment: I'm adding my button in IB